# Retrieving Listview row data (consisting of two TextView)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, classcastexception, onclicklistener

I'm having a `ListView`.  Each row of `ListView` contains 2 `TextView`.

I have implemented `setOnItemClickListener` for `ListView` as following:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            // String item = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            TextView item =(TextView)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }});
```

---

but it gives me **'ClassCastException'** as following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
at com.idealake.lic.Activities.PlansActivity$1.onItemClick(PlansActivity.java:62)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
```

---

My doubts are:

- How can I retrieve content of the `TextView` present within `ListView` row.
- How do I differentiate between 1st `TextView` and 2nd `TextView`, while retrieving data?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **findViewbyId()**

Instead of,

```
   TextView item =(TextView)list.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

try this,

```
   TextView item =(TextView)list.findViewbyId(R.id.textviewID);
```

In case if you find this to be not working then just try it with your view object like this,

```
  TextView item =(TextView)view.findViewbyId(R.id.textviewID);
```

Bcoz on a ItemCLick Listener, you will be provided with the exact element from the view which you are trying to reference. So you need not use position here once again to find your TextView.

Comment: +1 Gr8 answer Andro but i have a query.a list will have may rows and each row would have this id "R.id.textviewI" so list.findViewbyId(R.id.textviewID) will return which one ? Please help me out from this confusion ?

Comment: Well I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it. Actually you have are referring to a particular view here. I mean the ItemClick will return you the view of the item which is clicked. So it will be the only element that would be pointed. the object "view" refers to a particular child at that particular position only

Comment: `In case if you find this to be not working` You must sure while giving answer, I will go with Samir's answer as he answered the same before you.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't look at the object name of the View. I thought it was "list" and just went on with it. Edited it so quick :). thanks a ton though

Comment: @ GAMA are you sure ? :)............ because I am asking for "list.findViewbyId(R.id.textviewID)" and Andro have given two method (solution) I am clear with his second one but have doubt for first one....

Comment: never the less, +1 for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You can `setTag(id, value)` in your `getView()` and `getTag(id)` in `onItemClick()`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.xxx, null);
    TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    convertView.setTag(R.id.txt1, mTextView1);
    convertView.setTag(R.id.txt2, mTextView2);
    return convertView;
}
```

And in your List's Click listener do like this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        TextView mTextView1 =(TextView)view.getTag(R.id.txt1);
        TextView mTextView2 =(TextView)view.getTag(R.id.txt2);
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

optimize way is ::

```
TextView textview1 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                              ^^^^
TextView textview2 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            TextView item =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            TextView item =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        }});
```